# SMS gateway how to program android app

Tags: android, service, sms-gateway, standby, android-wake-lock

I want to make a SMS gateway app, that polls my website and checks if there are messages to send in the queue, and if there is, the app will send it to the destination number.

There should also be a callback function, where I will post information about the message, what android did exactly with it.

I thought first to create a service and do the poll check over wifi to the website, but refering to website "http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/" it is not possible to create a service that will run forever.

What should I take in mind by make this app possible. There a lot of tricks, like wakelocks, startforeground etc, but still the service will not run forever.

Thanks.

Shafqat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending sms messages: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

For checking/polling for new messages, probably the best way is using push messages. Since 2.2 this can be done with Cloud To Device Messaging: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html and http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/

That should work in the background, in the same way that gmail checks his mail (for example)

Comment: I have a device that will not be upgraded to version 2.2, so I have to create the app for 2.1.

Comment: There are alternatives to C2DM; like http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polling or long running requests you should use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) ... like what this app/lib does: http://netbizltd.com/wp/budget-sms-gateway/

Answer (score 0):

As that post recommends, you should use AlarmManager to handle periodic polling.

Comment: Can I also use AlarmManager for periodic polling of 5 seconds?

Comment: and what about will the alarm be prevented from to run when the cpu is in standby mode?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: (But waking up and polling every 5 minutes is expensive for the battery..)

Comment: that's no problem, the device will be always be attached with the charger.

Comment: If it's always plugged in, your main activity could maintain a WakeLock to make it stay awake. Just make sure that activity is running when you're not doing anything else with the phone, and it'll stay awake. Of course, if you're keeping an activity in the foreground then that activity can keep a Service running indefinitely so that's another option. It depends on whether you intend to be doing other stuff with the phone.